# how to read a file from blob and save it to public folder in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i am reading a pdf file from blob and saving it to  local folder

```
    @doc = Document.find(params[:id])
    blob = @doc.docs.first.blob
    
    ActiveStorage::Downloader.new(blob.service).open(blob.key, checksum: blob.checksum) do |tempFile|
        
        temppdf = Tempfile.new ["mypdf", ".pdf"]
        pathpdf = "app/assets/images/" + current_account.email+'.pdf'
        tempFile.save(pathpdf)

    end
```

Comment: What is your question? Does your code return an unexpected result? Or is there an error? What is the error message?

Comment: Error: NoMethodError (undefined method `save' for #<Tempfile: (closed)>)

Comment: thanks i have fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`ActiveStorage::Blob#open`](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#downloading-files) to steam the file directly to disk circumventing the tempfile:

```
@doc = Document.find(params[:id])
blob = @doc.docs.first.blob
# app/assets certainly isn't a public path...
fn = Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', 'mypdf.pdf')

File.open(fn, "wb+") do |file| 
  blob.download { |chunk| file.write(chunk) }
end
```

Comment: Ironically this is exactly what `ActiveStorage::Downloading` did but it was depreachiated. There should really be a method for this...

Comment: If the answer solved your problem you should accept it by clicking the checkmark.